# Java EE integration with Legacy C++ application

Tags: visual-c++, jakarta-ee, java-native-interface, jca

I'm developing a Java EE web application and it should be integrated with a legacy Visual C++ application (.dll file) to apply some business logic (using the .dll functions).

Could anyone point out how to implement this approach. I've done some google search and I read about JCA and JNI, but JNI is not guaranteed to function properly on the Application server.

I kind of have no clear direction. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping the .dll in a c++ application thats exposes the .dll methods as a service.

It does not have to be a SOAP webservice, but could be something lightweight like Protocol Buffers over ZeroMQ. I would consider this approach to be more testable and maintainable as you don't introduce the JNI complexity, and the C++ you will end up writing is just a tiny service wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JNI for your requirement.it is not that complex what you are thinking.using JBOSS Application Server you can write a java application wherein you load your c++ dll and connect it through JNI.most of the recent applications are using JNI to use native implementations which have been written long back to avoid the re-implementation.